# Creating bookmarks in iText

Tags: itext, bookmarks, outline

I have looked at sample code in creating outlines in iText. However, they involve a new instance of PdfWriter.

I have existing code that uses PdfStamper to create annotations to PDF. I tried to use stamper.getWriter() so i can get reference to getRootOutline() but it returns null.

even setting the stamper object to stamper.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageModeUseOutlines);

or the PdfReader object did not do the trick.

Am i missing something else here? or these are not the correct classes to use? If possible, I do not wish to re-open the file just to create bookmarks using the classes found in the sample code.

This is how my stamper and reader objects are created.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(srcPdf);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outputPdf));
```

Comment: Your code uses an old version of iText. Is upgrading to iText 7 an option?

Comment: Hi bruno. yes. i am using 5.5. I was under the assumption that 7 needs a commercial license and 5.5 does not? or am i wrong?

Comment: All software has a license. The license of iText 5 and iText 7 is identical. They are both available under the AGPL. That means that you can distribute iText for free (in a project, in a SaaS application,...) as long as you distribute your own source code for free as AGPL software too. If you want to use iText in a closed source environment, you need to purchase a commercial license. Please show me where it says that iText 5 and iText 7 have a different license so that I can take action to remove that incorrect information. Watch https://vimeo.com/207798908 for more info on using open source.

Comment: hi bruno. i misunderstood then. thank you for clearing this up. does this mean v5.5 will not suffice with regards to getting the root outline? and i would have to use v7 for this? thanks

Comment: I don't know. Maybe iText 5.5 will suffice, but I usually don't look at iText 5 anymore (iText 5 is being phased out; support is only available for paying customers), so if you're not a customer, you'll have to get help from someone else if you're not ready to migrate to iText 7.

Comment: I ended up using HashMap instead.